Does shared objects breaks encapsulation?
The encapsulation principle says : "You should hide the attributes of your class and only make them accessible via methods. This guarantees the validity of class invariants."
I'm totally agree with this principle, but i've been wondering : "does sharing the same object between several classes break encapsulation ?"
Example : we have an object of a class A.

class B has a reference to this object
class C has a reference to this object

It seems ridiculous because the point of OOP is let objects communicate between them, but the thing is a class that has a reference to this shared object can modify without passing through the methods of other classes so logically it breaks the encapsulation ?
For example : B modify the state of the object A without the agreement of C because it doesn't pass with its methods ? Same for C that doesn't pass via B.
I'm so confused with all these principles, I feel like they're all contradicting each other. Do I perhaps misunderstand the principle of encapsulation ?
public class A {
  private int value = 0;

  public void increment(){
    value += 1;
  }

  public void decrement() {
    value -= 1;
  }
}


public class B {
  private final A a;
  
  public B(A a){
    this.a = a;
  }

  public void doSomething(){
    // Do some stuff
    a.increment();
  }
}

public class C {
  private final A a;
  
  public C(A a){
    this.a = a;
  }

  public void doSomethingElse(){
    // Do some stuff
    a.decrement();
  }
}


What if they had copies of A instead of the same A? What if A is immutable? Also consider the Liskov substitution principle, can you replace A with any subclass of A?

Yes, sharing mutable state like this is indeed a light break of encapsulation. A few important things to realize:
It's not inevitable
Lots of classes are immutable. You can't change anything about them. Trivially, strings, for example. If 2 instances both 'share' a string, and one them calls x.toLowerCase(), nothing happens. Because toLowerCase() changes nothing. It makes an entirely new  string and returns it. If one class writes x = x.toLowerCase(), they are updating their reference - it does not modify the reference (nor the object) that the other class's field is referring to.
Sharing immutables therefore does not run into this issue.
The point of architectural debate
Here's one rule that has no exceptions: "Every rule has exceptions".
The principle of encapsulation is a guide. And, like all guidelines, true expertise involves knowing when to ignore them.
As a general principle, encapsulation has advantages.
But then, so does sharing state.
The advantages and disadvantages are completely different. So, it's a tradeoff: Code that you write that breaks encapsulation in certain ways has certain disadvantages. For example, it's hard to update one class without at least also taking into account you need to consider the impact it has on other classes involved in the 'break'. But, often, 2 classes are fundamentally related anyway - changing one without keeping in mind the other exists is a problem anyway. At which point, that particular disadvantage is irrelevant.
There are no simple guides. Even if you feel you are really good at reading architectural documentation like this, there's no real way to fully understand how to apply it without being an experienced programmer.
It's good news, and bad news: To be a good programmer you need to do it a lot and gain 10 years experience. The downside is: Shortcuts don't exist. The upside is: Shortcuts don't exist - so you can just ignore such concerns.
If some architectural design you come up with ends up being a disaster, and if you had put more effort in avoiding encapsulation would have avoided it, [A] that doesn't mean the alternative would have been any better, and [B] well, you know how beginner programmers turn into expert programmers? Via the tool known as 'the mistake'. Cherish them. And make sure you keep in mind that post mortems on your coding decisions is crucial. You should spend more time considering the full impact of the choices you have made in the past on how maintainable your software is today, than attempting to read well-intended philosophical gobbledygook about abstract concepts like 'encapsulation'. I'm not saying things like encapsulation are meaningless; not at all. I'm saying: Without having personal experience, it's incredibly difficult to meaningfully apply the advice.
Note that my earlier advice about immutables has to adhere to all this just the same. Do not go on a spree of 'I have seen the light and ALL SHALL BE IMMUTABLE! Time to toss out all our software and start  over!' - that's making the same mistake. It's a tool in the toolbox, if you keep running into issues that feel like 'encapsulation' is the issue, you might want to try a few features with more immutable architecture. Trust me, you'll run into a whole new set of disadvantages and maintenance headaches. But, now you learned, and now you can weigh the downsides of foregoing proper encapsulation against the downsides of overindexing on it. Next project you might finally be capable of making a good judgement on which tradeoff is the best for the project you're working on.

I think this is all true, but it also feels terribly unsatisfying from the perspective of a junior engineer. Trial and error is the only way to learn? It seems the software industry will struggle to ever advance if we can't learn from each other's mistakes, to avoid repeating them.

@rzwitserloot Thanks for your reply! I think I'll step back from all those good programming principles and just code. Usually, the answer to a programming question is "it's getting out of hand". This can be very frustrating for a novice (like me) because we don't have a clear answer, but the answer is totally right because we can only answer it with experience and therefore by making mistakes as you said. So, for now, my only guideline will be "code first and learn from your mistakes later".

This is an example of something called "Dependency Injection".
Class B and C both have a dependency on Class A which you are injecting via the constructor of the classes.
However be aware that the way you implement you objects should make sense in the real life context you are implementing them.
If you think of class A as class called Engine and Class B as a class called Car, it would not make sense to have one engine object for two car objects, therefore two objects should share one dependency object.
Dependency injection comes in handy, when you suddenly have a class that inherits from Engine. In that case you would just need to change the construction of the engine objects and not refactor every class that contains one engine.
See the following example.
public class Engine {
  private int kilometerCount = 0;

  public void incrementKm(){
    kilometerCount += 1;
  }

  public int getKilometerCount() {
    return kilometerCount;
  }
}

public class Car {
  private final Engine a;
  
  public C(Engine a){
    this.a = a;
  }

  public void drive(){
    // Do some stuff
    a.incrementKm();
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Engine engine = new Engine();
    Engine engine2 = new Engine();


    Car car = new Car(engine);
    Car car2 = new Car(engine2);

    car.drive();
    car2.drive();
    System.out.println(engine.getKilometerCount());
  }
}

And then you change the Modify the engine Class:

public class PowerfulEngine extends Engine {
  private int kilometerCount = 0;

  public void enableBoost(){
    System.out.println("Its hammer time!");
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Engine engine = new Engine();
    Engine engine2 = new PowerfulEngine();


    Car car = new Car(engine);

    engine2.enableBoost();
    Car car2 = new Car(engine2);

    car.drive();
    car2.drive();
    System.out.println(engine.getKilometerCount());
  }
}

Now only two lines have changed.
Note: I do not want to say that sharing one object never makes sense. Just that it needs to be useful in your context. 
I could imagine that a class named "Road" could be injected into multiple "Car" objects at a time, however this is incredibly dependent on your specific situation.
